# Problems with Existential Instantiation

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Why is it required to use a "fresh name/variable"? And because of that requirement, Existential instantiation always precedes universal instantiation. What I am thinking is, If we are picking elements at random from our universe of discourse then why can't universal instantiation pick that random element first before existential instantiation does? I would understand the rule that we cannot existentially instantiate more than one element(which will need more than one name/variable) because we can never be sure there is more than one, but the reason EI precedes UI in picking a random element eludes me.

**let's say we pick an object "a" for EI then use that same "a" for UI. when we picked "a" from the universe, its properties does not change even if we universally instantiate first or existentially instantiate first.**

Comment: I was always under the impression we wanted to use a "fresh name/variable" to avoid [name collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision)...

Comment: i share that idea too, but is there anything else?

Comment: "Existential instantiation always precedes universal instantiation" -- Not following. For example when we define continuity in calculus we say "for every epsilon there exists delta ..." There are lots of other examples. Can you clarify your remark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EI rule formalizes the fact that if we know that **∃xP(x)**, we are licensed to give to "that **P**" a name.

But we have to avoid that the said name is not already "in use" because, if so, it may denote an object that has some properties incompatible with its "being **P**".

This intuitive restriction is formalized with the proviso : the *term* (variable or constant) must be "fresh", i.e. not already used in the context of the proof involving the EI rule.

---

There is no reason why EI must always precede UI.

The "trick" is: if we introduce a term **a** by UI applied to e.g. **∀xQ(x)**, then - due to the above restriction - we cannot use the same **a** in an application of EI to e.g. **∃xP(x)** : intuitively, the fact that an object whatever satisfy **Q** does not mean that it must be "the **P**".

If instead we introduce a "fresh" term **a** by EI, we can use it later in applying UI to e.g. **∀xP(x)**. The reason is simple: whatever **a** is, if **P** holds for all, it necessarily holds also for **a**.

Comment: i have also thought of the intuitive reason behind it. However, after contemplating on the methods by which we instantiate, i think what really bothers me is the fact that whether we use UI or EI, we pick an object at random. Which leads me to think that If we pick one object at random to be existentially instantiated first then universally instantiated then our chances of picking the "right" object will remain constant since we are doing it once for UI and EI and we are picking that object from one universe of discourse. That is why I do not think it should matter if EI or UI must go first.

Comment: @TheLastCipher - to be precise, we do not "pick an object at random". With UI, **every** object will do, becuase "all" means ... all. With EI, we pick **that** object; the only !trick" is that we introduce a new name for it.

Comment: it's very abstract, but yes i do now acknowledge that there is a slight but significant difference of the order of using EI and UI. i think i completely understand now. thank you! also i picked up a concrete example from the book i am reading about why it is mandatory to always use a new name:                                                                                                     ∃xFx, 
∃xGx
/ ∃x(Fx & Gx) which could be translated as there is at least one even number, there is at least one odd number, therefore must be at least one number that is odd and even which makes it wrong

Comment: @TheLastCipher - exactly; we have to instantiate **∃xFx** with **a** and **∃xGx** with **b**, because we have no reason to assume that the two are the same object, and in the case even-odd they cannot be.